# Ajax patterns - assume success or wait for response

Tags: javascript, ajax

Typically an ajax interaction would involve sending the request, providing feedback to the user that the request is in process, then once the response arrives handle it.

Waiting for the response is obviously unavoidable when the next action requires the data sent from the server but what if the interaction is an update to the some data on the server such as sorting the order of a list. Would it be bad practice to assume success? So you'd make the request and simply update the DOM based on the assumption that the sort will be successful. I'd imagine you'd then have to provide a rollback method should the request fail as well as notify the user but 99% of the time the request should go through and appear instantaneous to the user.

Is this a common pattern and are there any other factors that should be considered other than a rollback and notification method?

Any advice would be much appreciated,
Rich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to take a look at the command pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern. It looks like you want to modify some data and assume that the server gets modified as well. If the AJAX handler fails than you can rollback the command (and notify the user).

Comment: An interesting read, I definitely like having a name for patterns, will have to investigate further.

Answer (score 1):

If the user is to receive feedback about the success or not, then it would be bad practice to assume success.

Just return a success/fail response from the server, and let the user know that their action was successful.  You're not really losing anything by this extra trip back from the server, and any request *could* potentially fail.

Comment: But it would improve the UX tenfold for those times when the request is successful which, for a simple update request, I'd hazard a guess would occur 99% of the time...

Comment: @risc, is that 99% of the time under normal conditions? What happens when your app is not experiencing normal conditions?

Comment: @riscarrott: It really depends on the use case.  Abdullah's answer is good for certain use cases.  If the update is important, showing the update before server confirmation could entice the user to navigate away from the page or close the browser thinking they had performed the update.

Comment: @Dave Well that's the point in the rollback method, when the app isn't experiencing normal conditions the UI will be rolled back and the user notified, the only difference would be that there isn't any feedback when the request is being made.

Comment: @riscott: how does the user get notified that the update failed after they close the browser, thinking it succeeded?

Comment: @Gerrat - well yes, this is where I think you're right in saying it depends on the use case. An example of this I've just come across can be found when renaming a document in Google docs, the DOM is updated whilst the request is still in process... it's hard however to work out how they'd handle an error after the DOM is updated.